# Exact value of integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(\sec x-x)(\sec x+x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

In terms of integration, how would you obtain the "exact-value" of $$\int_{0}^\frac\pi4(\sec x-x)(\sec x+x)dx.$$

Note: $1+\tan^2x=\sec^2x$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\int \text{sec}^2(x)dx=\tan(x)+C.$$

Comment: Why is it not$\int \text{sec}^2(x)dx=x+\tan(x)+C.$

Comment: ?? because $$\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d x}\tan(x)=1+\tan^2(x).$$

Comment: Is it not $tan(x)'=sec^2x$

Comment: are you joking ? Of course it is ! (see the *Note* in your original post)

Comment: Why the wrong answer then???

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: I think OP forgot $\sec^2(x)$ is $1+\tan^2(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(\sec x -x)(\sec x+x)\ dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(\sec^2 x -x^2)\ dx$$
$$=\left(\tan x -\frac{x^3}{3}\right)_{0}^{\pi/4}$$
$$=\tan \frac{\pi}{4} -\frac{\frac{\pi^3}{4^3}}{3}-0$$
$$=\color{red}{1-\frac{\pi^3}{192}}$$